# Sum of previous elements from an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript array with these values:

```
fbDivHeightsTest = [280,430,408,430,408]
```

I need a new array with the sum of elements like this:

```
newArray = [280, 710, 1118, 1548, 1956].
```

The `fbDivHeightsTest[0] + fbDivHeightsTest[1], fbDivHeightsTest[0] + fbDivHeightsTest[1] + fbDivHeightsTest[2]` and so on.

I have tried like this, but the reduce function is not returning the result I expect. It returns: 280, 710, 1398, 2818, 5614

```
sectionsSeclector.each(function(index, item) {    
    var sum = fbDivHeights.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
    fbDivHeights.push( $(item).outerHeight() + sum);       
});
```

Can you please help me with this? thanks!

Comment: You are mixing up data here which might be a problem to verify right values. E.g., something like `$(item).outerHeight()` should not be part of your function.

Comment: var_nn=[];var sum  = fbDivHeights.reduce(function(a, b)
{return _nn.push( a + b); });

Comment: @GeorgeJempty, that is not the duplicate of that you wrote.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai I know, I rescinded my close vote

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `reduce` method in combination with `map` method.

The `reduce()` method applies a function against an **accumulator** and each element in the `array` (from left to right) to **reduce** it to a **single** value.

```js
let array = [280,430,408,430,408];
array = array.map((elem, index) => array.slice(0,index + 1).reduce((a, b) => a + b));
console.log(array);
```

You can also use only `map` method.

```js
let array = [280,430,408,430,408],sum;
array = array.map(elem => sum = (sum || 0) + elem);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 11):

You could use a closure over the actual sum and map the incremented result.

> **How it works**:
>
> Assuming the function is called, then
>
> ```
> (s => a => s += a)(0)
> //                 ^  value for s
> ```
>
> it returns
>
> ```
> a => s += a      // s = 0
> ```
>
> for the callback of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and for every loop,
>
> ```
> 280 => s += 280  // s =  280
> 430 => s += 430  // s =  710
> 408 => s += 408  // s = 1118
> 430 => s += 430  // s = 1548
> 408 => s += 408  // s = 1956
> ```

```js
var array =[280, 430, 408, 430, 408],
    result = array.map((s => a => s += a)(0));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I just don't understand

Comment: @Faly, this code is equivalent to `array.map(function (s) {
  return function (a) {
    return s += a;
  };
}(0));`

Comment: Does a => s += a returns s + a ?

Comment: @Faly, right it's an [addition assignment `+=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment) operator.

Answer (score 3):

javascript [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b) function will do the job for you easily:-

```js
var fbDivHeightsTest = [280,430,408,430,408] 
var new_array = [];
fbDivHeightsTest.reduce(function(a,b,i) { return new_array[i] = a+b; },0);
console.log(new_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

the `reduce()` (sometimes also called fold) method is intended to "reduce" an Array to a single value *(although that single value can be an object or list)*

In your example, you son't want a sum of the list, but you want to map (1:1) for each value in the initial arrray, the sum of the values to this point:

```js
let array = [280,430,408,430,408];
let _sum = 0;
let sums = array.map(value => _sum += value);

console.log(sums);
```

Or as mentioned, you reduce one list to another:

```js
let array = [280, 430, 408, 430, 408];
let sums = array.reduce((results, value, index) => {
  let previousSum = index>0? results[index-1]: 0;
  results.push(previousSum + value);
  
  return results;
}, []);

console.log(sums);
```

where `results` is an intermediate Result

Answer (score 1):

Just use array.reduce:

```js
var fbDivHeightsTest = [280,430,408,430,408] ;
var res = fbDivHeightsTest.reduce((m, o, i) => {
  var prev = m[i - 1];
  if (prev) {
    o = o + prev;
  } 
  m.push(o);
  return m;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another reducer ;)

```js
const cumulative = [280,430,408,430,408]
       .reduce( (p, n) => p.concat((+p.slice(-1) || 0) + n), []);
 
console.log(cumulative);
```